# Can I create an exception for pre middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Using node.js and mongoose, I have a basic `/login` route. In the database, there is a boolean `active: true|false` state property. When a user deletes their account using `/deleteme` route it to `active: false` and the user appears nowhere using schema.pre middleware /^find/. But I want to reactivate the user's account whenever they try to log in. But it won't work because the user can't be found since the pre-middleware prevents the user to be found using any find method.

So long story short, can I create an exception to my schema.pre middleware that it will not get executed if it gets called by a specific middleware?

```
router.post('/login', authController.login);
router.delete('/deleteMe', userController.deleteMe);
```

```
userSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.find({ active: { $ne: false } });
  next();
});
```

```
exports.deleteMe = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, { active: false });

  res.status(204).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: null,
  });
});
```

````
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password', 400));
  }

  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

  if (!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email or password', 401));
  }

  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user.id, { active: true });
  createSendToken(user, 200, res);
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `updateOne` method.

```
exports.deleteMe = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  await User.updateOne({_id: req.user.id}, { active: false });

  res.status(204).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: null,
  });
});
```

Comment: deleteMe middleware was not the the solution, neither the req.user.id, beucase its a login operation, there is no info about the user except for the input email address. But indeed the User.updateOne() was very helpful. 

  await User.updateOne(
    {
      $eq: {
        email,
      },
    },
    { $set: { active: true } },
    { runValidators: true },
  );

This is how I did it inside the login route middleware. Thank you so much.